# Show Admob Native Ads Programmatically with Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, admob

The official guide is using storyboard
https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/ios/native-express

I am trying to load the native ads in the `header` of `UITableView` without using storyboard.

What I have tried:

```
    @property (nonatomic, strong) GADNativeExpressAdView *nAdView;
...
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
        _nAdView.adUnitID = @"ca-app-pub-mycode";
        _nAdView.rootViewController = self;
}
...
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
        GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
        [self.nAdView loadRequest:request];
        return _nAdView;
}
```

But nothing happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your nAdView related to Storyboard? I think it is not.
Maybe you have to correlate GADNativeExpressAdView instance to Storyboard.
And then, you should load native ad like Google official site does:

```
@import GoogleMobileAds;

@interface ViewController ()

@property(nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet GADNativeExpressAdView *nativeExpressAdView;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];

  self.nativeExpressAdView.adUnitID = @"ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2562852117";
  self.nativeExpressAdView.rootViewController = self;

  GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
  [self.nativeExpressAdView loadRequest:request];
}

@end
```

**Edit:**

Without storyboard, try this:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) GADNativeExpressAdView *nAdView;

- (void)ViewDidLoad {
  self.nAdView = [[GADNativeExpressAdView alloc] initWithAdSize:GADAdSizeFromCGSize(CGSizeMake(width, GADAdViewHeight))];
  self.nAdView.adUnitID = @"ca-app-pub-mycode";
  self.nAdView.rootViewController = self;
  self.nAdView.delegate = self;
  [self.nAdView loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
  return self.nAdView;
}

- (void)nativeExpressAdView:(GADNativeExpressAdView *)nativeExpressAdView
    didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(GADRequestError *)error {
  NSLog(@"Failed to receive ad: %@", error.localizedDescription);
  [self.nAdView loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the incomplete question. What I'm trying to achieve is to load the native ads programatically without using storyboard.

Comment: @user2872856 Did you initialize (instantiate) `GADNativeExpressAdView`? It doesn't seem that you instantiate GADNativeExpressAdView.

Comment: @user2872856 This official sample code will help you. [link](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-ios-examples/blob/master/Objective-C/advanced/NativeExpressTableViewExample/NativeExpressTableViewExample/TableViewController.m)

Comment: How to initialise `GADNativeExpressAdView`? I can't find the sample code from official site.

Comment: @user2872856 `[[GADNativeExpressAdView alloc] initWithAdSize:size];`
you can find also in this link:
https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/adx/ios/api/reference/Classes/GADNativeExpressAdView#/c:objc(cs)GADNativeExpressAdView(im)initWithAdSize: